# Meaning of "Compensation for Damage" in a clinical trial; vs. "Compensation of Injury"

Tags: legal-terms

I'm translating a document that is presented to clinical trial participants prior to their enrollment.

One section is titled "Compensation for Injury":

> **Compensation for Injury**
> Will you receive any compensation if you have an injury/illness related to your participation in the study?
> According to the insurance contract, in case of health injury, the Insurance Company will compensate you according to the following conditions:

and so on. It describes in detail what kinds of injuries and illnesses will be compensated and how. The next section is titled "Compensation for Damage":

> **Compensation for Damage**
> Since this is an observational study, no investigational medication will be used and no additional procedures or tests will be performed during the study. Therefore we do not expect that you will suffer any damage due to your participation.

And this is all. This section is a mere stopgap compared with the previous one; so it's hard to understand what the authors mean by distinguishing "damage" from "injury".

I don't know how to translate this title into Russian. What is the difference between damage and injury in this context? Both seem to imply some kind of bodily harm, isn't it? Why not lump them into a single section then?

P.S. [I also asked this question on Medical Sciences SE. I'm not sure where to ask](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24033/meaning-of-compensation-for-damage-in-a-clinical-trial-vs-compensation-of-i).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of English.

The word injury, in this context, normally refers to injuries to one's body.

The word damage can be a more general word referring to damage to health or property, but, in this context and most others, it means damage to property only, so not to a living body.

In general, if your body is hurt, you will say "I'm injured", not "I'm damaged": the latter is what Commander Data in Star Trek would say, because he is a robot.